# PBS deferred execution with job array

Tags: job-scheduling, pbs, deferred-execution

I'm trying to write a job array so that the individual jobs start at slightly different points in time. (Because the program I evoke uses the time of day to the nearest second as a random seed and it will generate identical results if all jobs are submitted at the same time.)

Here are the directives I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test
#PBS -t 1-10                   # Job array
#PBS -a hhmm.ss                # Deferred execution

echo Time is `date` >> test.out
```

But I would like the -a to be spaced out. I was thinking of writing a little subroutine that prints out random numbers in that format and feeding it to -a, but I don't know how to make the option that -a takes a variable.

Solutions along any other lines are welcome, the only requirements are that the jobs in the job array start spaced out by random intervals of time.

Hope this makes sense, if not I will be happy to clarify.

Comment: You can force that none of the jobs execute at the same time by changing the #PBS -t 1-10 to #PBS -t 1-10%1 if this is TORQUE 2.4 or higher. If you can edit the program, I would strongly suggest using a different random seed, as there are vastly superior ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N test
#PBS -t 1-10                   # Job array

sleep `expr $RANDOM % 60`     
echo Time is `date` >> test.out
```

A friend suggested to use wait or sleep at the beginning of the script to make the job wait before starting again. This expr $RANDOM % 60 spaces them out a matter of seconds (less than 60). Notice that you no longer need to defer execution (no -a directive).